# Ruby hash hardcoding programming best practices

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I'm reading about ruby programming best practices and I found this page: https://github.com/styleguide/ruby

Inside this, a "Hashes" section explain that:

```
# bad
user = {
  login: "defunkt",
  name: "Chris Wanstrath"
}

# bad
user = {
  login: "defunkt",
  name: "Chris Wanstrath",
  "followers-count" => 52390235
}

# good
user = {
  :login => "defunkt",
  :name => "Chris Wanstrath",
  "followers-count" => 52390235
}
```

Why the first block are marked as **bad** if I can read better than the last block?

Comment: the answer to this is in the book: "Use hashrocket syntax for Hash literals instead of the JSON style introduced in 1.9." Basically it's got to do with the actual syntax more than anything else. Colons(:) and hash rockets (=>) are the preferred way of writing ruby. Hope it helps

Comment: Looks like this guide is outdated. Use https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#symbols-as-keys instead.

Comment: @pragma, lots of good stuff there. I've read it several times, and each time I implant a few good tips. This time I was reminded about the goodness of `Hash#fetch`.

Comment: Another thing to note is to use single quotes in place of double quotes for strings without interpolation. For example : user = { name: 'Nazeef' }

Answer (score 1):

It's just a style guide GitHub uses for its code base, nothing more. They probably prefer it because a lot of their code had been written before Ruby 1.9 was established and they want to keep things consistent.

I personally use the new syntax everywhere I can. Note that the last example is bad on its own because it mixes symbol and string keys together.

Answer (score 0):

When `String` key hash mixed with `Symbol` key hash, it's "better" to make them similar to each other. 
P.S. But i'm not agreed with it.

That's wrong with first example it is really difficult to say.